# Best way to save json data and files in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am developing a react-native application. I want it to get a json file online and print it as a list, showing the image and by clicking, showing the pdf. Here is my json :

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "nb_edit":0,
      "nom":"Catalog 1",
      "description":"test",
      "apercu":"img\/1.png",
      "pdf":"pdf\/1.pdf"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "nb_edit":"0",
      "nom":"Hi",
      "description":"yes",
      "apercu":"img\/2.png",
      "pdf":"pdf\/2.pdf"
   }
]
```

It actually works fine. But now, I want to add an offline mode. For this, I want to basically set a version variable in the application to 0, and check if the version on the website (version.txt) is the same. If yes, just load the json file saved in the phone (the png and pdf are saved too). If not, download the json, update the json saved locally, update the version variable, and then load the files from the phone.
Do you have an idea of how could I do? I thought about using redux-persist for the version, but will it work for the json, the images and the pdfs, and how?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: redux-persist will help you to save JSON data in asyncStorage of you RN application, and you access this JSON from redux store and update this as per your requirements and whenever you want.
To save images, pdf or any other files in you device, you can use  `react-native-fetch-blob` npm module to save these files in file-system or save them as `base-64` in `redux-persist`.
then you can serve them from redux-persist.

Comment: I think it is what I was looking for, I'm going to have a look at this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would not try to save the file to the device. Instead of trying to save the file, I would save data to the device's storage by using `AsyncStorage` (If the file is not that big). If you go in this way, do not forget to stringify the object while saving the object to the storage.

You may use `react-native-fs` for saving files such as pdf, images.

Comment: Ok thank you, the max size will be 30kB, I think it will be ok. But how can I do with the images and the pdfs (up to 250MB) ?

Comment: for images and pdfs, I would use file system packages. Due to the fact that I do not have any idea which package you should use, I couldn't help with that :/

Comment: I will have a look at this. Thanks! ;)

Comment: @bouldererdouze I have searched and I found the package which is called `react-native-fs`. It probably will help you in your case.

Comment: Is this still a reliable package for large json information in 2022 ?

Comment: Frankly, I haven't used that package in any project. I don't have any comment regarding that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

**Option1:**

> AsyncStorage is an unencrypted, asynchronous, persistent, key-value
>   storage system that is global to the app. It should be used instead of
>   LocalStorage.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage.html

**Option2:**
Local database

> SQLite is an open-source SQL database that stores data to a text file
>   on a device.  It supports all the relational database features. In
>   order to access this database, we don’t need to establish any kind of
>   connections for it like JDBC, ODBC.

react-native-sqlite-storage
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage